# Ubuntu - How close/far is this from Red Hat

Tags: ubuntu

Out of the blue, my company has asked me to switch to Ubuntu for OS needs (from Windows 8).
My last experience with a Linux was several years back with a Red Hat edition.

a) Can i assume that all the Linux commands that I can execute on Red Hat will work in Ubuntu..at-least the commonly used ones like file operations/package/compiling etc
or Should I have to learn a whole new jargon for working with Ubuntu ?

b) Is it possible to have a laptop that dual boots between Windows/Ubuntu ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not even remotely about programming.


Comment: And the answers are very easy to find with Google. a) yes/no/yes. b) Yes.

Comment: This might be a good question for http://superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Most of the commands in terminal will be the same, however, for package managing you would use `apt-get`. Otherwise, everything else should be the same

b) Yes, it is possible to have a laptop that dual boots between Windows/Ubuntu. Check out this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot